# saving file with ofstream

Tags: c++, base64, ofstream

I'm new to C++, I have an image named "test.jpg", i convert it to base64 and decode it again like this:

```
std::ifstream  inputFile;
inputFile.open("test.jpg",std::ios::binary);
std::filebuf* pbuf = inputFile.rdbuf();

inputFile.seekg (0, ios::end);
int length = inputFile.tellg();

// allocate memory to contain file data
 char* buffer=new char[length];

// get file data
pbuf->sgetn (buffer,length);
inputFile.close();
CBase64 base64;
string encodedData = base64.base64_encode((unsigned char*)buffer,length);
delete[] buffer;

string decodedData = base64.base64_decode(encodedData);

ofstream outPutFile;
outPutFile.open("test2.jpg",ios::binary | ios::out);
outPutFile.write(decodedData.c_str(), decodedData.length());
outPutFile.close();
```

the "test2.jpg" has exact same size as "test.jpg"(the original file) but, i can't open it.
i couldn't find what is the problem.

Comment: Some observations on your code and some counter questions.
What do you mean you cannot open your test2.jpg? In file explorer?
Why are you opening test2.jpg in binary mode and then writing ANSI C string in the file? That can well be done using text mode.

Comment: yes, i mean in file explorer. that's for previous test where i wrote binary data on the file

Comment: Ohh, I just realised. You are decoding base64 string again to a string! Which is disastrous. You do not know when your string is going to be terminated due to zeros in your binary output of decoded data. Besides, I am not very sure about the result of writing base64 encoded data in JPG file. The file explorer would not understand it. There doesn't seem any problem with your file writing logic.

Comment: so, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

i got it working. i just replaced:

```
outPutFile.open("test2.jpg",ios::binary | ios::out);
```

with

```
outPutFile.open("test2.jpg", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: great solution! taking into account that ios::binary == ios_base::binary and ios_base::out == ios::out! http://ideone.com/qY3XB0

Comment: I had a similar issue where I was able to open the image but the image was corrupt.  Adding the additional options fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string path = "file.txt";
std::string cfgString = "data";
std::ofstream output(path.c_str(), ios_base::out | std::ios::binary);
if (output.is_open()) {
    output.write(cfgString.data(), cfgString.length());
}

output.close();
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain why your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no superficial problem with your file writing logic even though there are some irregularities. The biggest problem is in your main logic.

The program seems to be simple program of copying a file. What you are doing is reading a file, converting its data to base64 string and then again decoding the data to `std::string`. Now one small problem. Conversion of base64 string cannot be successfully done into a null terminated ANSI string for obvious reasons that any 0 in decoded binary data will terminate the string prematurely. Secondly you are opening a file in binary mode to write but trying to write `std::string` in the file. But that doesn't matter as you data has already been corrupted in your previous operation.

To solve this, you can simply use file copying example as [this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14262) or make sure you write only binary data with care to your output file which means read in binary from input file and write to output file the same buffer. No base64 encoding decoding is required.

Comment: the purpose is not copying a file. this is just for test. the main program takes an image, converts it to Base64 and stores it on database and another program reads this Base64 data and shows the image

Comment: I ran another test and the data in "buffer" is exactly like the data in "decodedData"

Comment: Yes I agree that use of base64 is generally to store data or transmit data but then in this case what you are doing is wrong. If you want to write base64 encoded data to a file then simply write that data. Don't decode and write it. That does not make sense. Besides, also do not expect the file explorer to read base64 encoded data of a file and display the image correctly. Also, how did you compare the data in "buffer" and "deocdedData"? By printing or equating it? Both these methods will give you false results. You need to print the data in hex to compare it.

Comment: i have decoded it to find out that i can create image file from it. as i said before, here i just testing stuff

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you forgot to write

```
inputFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
```

after getting file length. it means you try to read from the end of the file instead of its beginning.

Comment: Yes, but that's not causing any problem

Comment: what do u mean "not causing any problem"?
pbuf->sgetn (buffer,length); reads nothing.
i reproduced your problem and wrote about the solution that fixes it.